# How to return Json result with 404 status code

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am using ASP.NET Web API 2 and I want to return a json result from my API with the error code 404.

I am trying to mimic [this result](https://api.github.com/users/no-such-user-exists):
[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
[RoutePrefix("error")]
public class ErrorController : MyBaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("notfound")]
    public IHttpActionResult NotFoundMessage()
    {
        return MyNotFound(new { Message = "Not douns", DocumentationUrl = "My documentation path" });
    }

    protected IHttpActionResult MyNotFound<T>(T t)   
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t));
    }
}
```

The above returns a serialized json but the problem is that the content type is not json.

I want to return something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("notfound")]
public IHttpActionResult NotFoundMessage()
{
    return Json(new { Message = "Not found", DocumentationUrl = "My documentation path" });
}
```

but the problem is, Json does not accept the status code and returns 200

Answer (score 1):

In case of ASP.NET WebAPI you can use `Content` for that.

[`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.content?view=aspnet-webapi-5.2)'s first parameter is the status code and the second is a string (already serialized response body)

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, responseObjectInJson);
```

---

Please bear in mind that in newer ASP.NET versions the [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.content?view=aspnetcore-7.0) does not have an overload which can accept `StatusCode`. In that case you can use the [`NotFound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-notfound(system-object)) with any object and ASP.NET will serialize it on your behalf.

```
return NotFound(responseObject);
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

I've overlooked that part where you have stated that the content-type is not set. You can set it if you are not using the `Content` method rather than the `ContentResult` object directly

```
return new ContentResult
{
    Content = responseObjectInJson,
    ContentType = "application/json",
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/action-method-return-type-in-web-api) this tutorial and created a create a custom HttpActionResult

```
public class CustomResult<TResultData> : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private readonly HttpStatusCode _httpStatusCode;
    private readonly TResultData _resultData;

    public CustomResult(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, TResultData resultData)
    {
        _request = request;
        _httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        _resultData = resultData;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = _request.CreateResponse(_httpStatusCode, _resultData);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

I also created my own BaseApiController:

```
public class MyBaseApiController : ApiController
{
    protected IHttpActionResult NotFound<TResultData>(TResultData resultData)
    {
        return new CustomResult<TResultData>(Request, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, resultData);
    }

    protected IHttpActionResult ServerError<TResultData>(TResultData resultData)
    {
        return new CustomResult<TResultData>(Request, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, resultData);
    }
}
```

Now I can use the above base class to return json result with 404 status code:

```
[RoutePrefix("error")]
public class ErrorController : MyBaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("notfound")]
    public IHttpActionResult NotFoundMessage()
    {
        return NotFound(new { Message = "Not found", DocumentationUrl = "My documentation path" });
    }
}
```